# Creating and sending vCard files via MMS

Tags: python, twilio, vcf-vcard, vobject

I'm trying to send vCard files (which allow you to save contacts on mobile devices) using Twilio's API and [vobject](https://github.com/eventable/vobject).

Here's my code:

```
import vobject
import requests
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'MY_SID_HIDDEN'
auth_token = 'AUTH_TOKEN_HIDDEN'

j = vobject.vCard()
j.add('n')
j.n.value = vobject.vcard.Name(family='Harris', given='Jeffrey')
j.add('fn')
j.fn.value = 'Jeffrey Harris'
j.add('email')
j.email.value = 'jeffrey@osafoundation.org'
j.email.type_param = 'Internet'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

client.api.account.messages.create(
    to="NUMBER_HIDDEN",
    from_="NUMBER_HIDDEN",
    body=j
)
```

When my device receives the message, it looks like this:

`<VCARD| [<EMAIL{'TYPE': ['Internet']}jeffrey@osafoundation.org>, <FN{}Jeffrey Harris>, <N{} Jeffrey  Harris >]>`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do, but there are a couple issues.

1. **Vcards are files**; you have put marked up text in a text field (body).
2. For attaching files using the API, you **point** it at a **URL that the Twilio Server can access** and make sure you properly declare your mime-type encoding in the API and on server where the card will be stored.

**Note:** I'm not sure if the mime-type is required anymore, as they don't use it on this example for a attaching picture (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages#send-a-message-with-an-image-url ; change the language to python).

You would attach the file (vcard) using mediaUrl.
ex// `mediaUrl=https://qrstuff.com/vcard.download/dec91a6d6/yo_yo_ma_vCard.vcf`

Comment: So you're saying my approach isn't feasible? What if I were to send the vCards as emails instead of texts?

Comment: Your options are to dynamically create a vcard and publish it to the web on the fly. Or just serve static (pre-made) cards (ex// qrstuff.com/vcard.download/dec91a6d6/yo_yo_ma_vCard.vcf ) For both options you would attached it using mediaUrl. see example in updated post, as i can't properly display in the comment